# Left invariant Vector Field on $S^2$

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-groups, intuition, invariance

How intuitively look like all left invariant vector fields on this manifold: the 2 dimensional unit sphere
$S^2$ with the smooth structure inherited from $\mathbb R^3$?

Why all left invariant vector fields on $\mathbb R^n$ are constant?
One answer to the second question might be, that they are invariant under all translations; but why this is so by the definition of left-invariance?

Comment: On $S^2$, what do you mean by left invariant?

Comment: Sorry, Sphere is not a Lie algebra,a necessary condition for the definition of left invariance?

Comment: Well, it's certainly sufficient to talk about left invariance.  I would also use the term "left invariant" if you were considering a left and right action on your space simultaneously.

Comment: You mean the sphere isn't a Lie group. What do you think invariance means?